# Header and Footer do not scroll with Body

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage I am working on. Currently, the header and footer stay on the page. The only portion that scrolls is the Body. The scroll bar only appears in the Body section of the page. I am trying to figure out how to change it so that the entire page scrolls instead of just one section with the rest being locked into place. I've tried removing "position: fixed" from my css, but that didn't change anything other than completely removing the footer from the screen.

This is my CSS

```
/********************************
*         Shared Layout         *
********************************/
#header {
    padding: 5px 0px 0px 20px;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    height: 170px;
    background-color: #000;
}

.logo-image {
    float: left;
    margin: 7px 20px 0px 0px;
}

.clear-fix:after {
    content: ".";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

body {
    background-color:#efeeef;
    color: #333;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#body {
    top: 170px; bottom: 130px;
    background-color: #efeeef;
    clear: both;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: absolute;
}

.content-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1125px;
}

#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    clear: both;
    background-color: #000;
    font-size: .8em;
    height: 130px;
    color: #FFF;

}

#footer, #body, #header {
    left: 0; right: 0;
}

#follow-icons {
     padding-top: 13px;
     float: right;
}

#logo-table {
    clear: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#logo-table td{
    padding: 0px 10px;
}

.float-left {
    float: left;
}

.float-right {
    float: right;
}
```

This is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Atlas Web Pages</title>
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="-webkit-box-shadow:3px 2px 15px #3D3D3D">
        <header id="header">
            <div class="web-header">
                <div class="logo-image">
                    <img style="vertical-align:top" src="~/Images/WebPageLogo.png" height="85" width="820" alt="Atlas Logo" />
                    <br />
                    <div style="color:#FFF">*A southpaw's approach to bowling*</div>
                </div>
                <div class="float-right">
                    <nav>
                        <ul id="menu">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("The Team", "About", "About")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Current Line-Up", "CurrentList", "Current")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Retired Equipment", "RetiredList", "Retired")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Tournaments", "TourneyInfo", "Tournament")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Bowling Videos", "Videos", "Video")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Sponsors", "Sponsors", "Sponsor")</li>   
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="body">
            @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">

                @RenderBody()
            </section>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div id="footer">
                <div class="content-wrapper">
                    <div class="float-left">
                        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year: Southpaw Web Solutions&trade; - Email: jmilam90@gmail.com</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="follow-icons">
                            <a href ="www.facebook.com/jmilam90"><img src="~/Images/FBIcon.png" alt="Follow on Facebook" height="40" width="40" /></a>
                            <a href ="www.twitter.com/jmilam900"><img src="~/Images/TwitIcon.png" alt="Follow on twitter" height="40" width="40" /></a>
                            <a href ="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCCSdkWipauQ1mhzEPAJfOnA"><img src="~/Images/YTIcon.png" alt="Subscribe on Youtube" height="40" width="40" /></a>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <table id="logo-table">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img src="~/Images/Logos/MBW.png" width="99" height="60" alt="McCorveys Bowling World Logo" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <img src="~/Images/Logos/EboniteLogo.png" width="93" height="60" alt="Ebonite Logo" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <img src="~/Images/Logos/TrackLogo.png" width="152" height="60" alt="Track Bowling Logo" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <img src="~/Images/Logos/HammerLogo.png" width="100" height="60" alt="Hammer Bowling Logo" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <img src="~/Images/Logos/ColumbiaLogo.png" width="123" height="60" alt="Columbia 300 Logo" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <img src="~/Images/Logos/PBALogo.png" width="60" height="60" alt="PBA Logo" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </footer>
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone tell me what needs to be removed/changed to allow the entire page to scroll?

Comment: It's definitely a combination of position:fixed and something else. Please post your HTML so we can see how the page is laid out. Also, while it's not necessarily bad practice, I don't recommend naming any IDs or classes the same name as any HTML elements (body and #body). You could get confused and accidentally edit the wrong CSS.

Comment: I updated it to show the HTML and I appreciate the advice on naming. I will make sure to take that into consideration as I continue on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the HTML it looks like you need to:

1. Remove `position: fixed;` on `#header` and `#footer`  as well as the now redundant `top` and `bottom`.
2. The problem is also caused by `top: 170px; bottom: 130px;` and `position: absolute` on `#body`. Remove `#body` completely.
3. Remove the now redundant:

```
#footer, #body, #header {
    left: 0; right: 0;
}
```

You are left with:

```
#header {
    height:170px;
    background-color:#000
}

.logo-image {
    float:left;
    margin:7px 20px 0 0
}

.clear-fix:after {
    content:".";
    clear:both;
    display:block;
    height:0;
    visibility:hidden
}

body {
    background-color:#efeeef;
    color:#333;
    font-size:.85em;
    font-family:"Segoe UI",Verdana,Helvetica,Sans-Serif;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden
}

.content-wrapper {
    margin:0 auto;
    max-width:1125px
}

#footer {
    clear:both;
    background-color:#000;
    font-size:.8em;
    height:130px;
    color:#FFF
}

#follow-icons {
    padding-top:13px;
    float:right
}

#logo-table {
    clear:left;
    margin:0 auto
}

#logo-table td {
    padding:0 10px
}

.float-left {
    float:left
}

.float-right {
    float:right
}
```

Comment: But I now I have a new problem. If the page content doesn't fill enough of the screen, the footer doesn't stay at the bottom of the screen. It stays directly under the content. [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/IKOTEew.jpg)

Comment: @AtlasBowler look up sticky footer on google. There's lots of resources describing how to solve that.

Comment: I ended up just taking the footer completely off. It was just a little extra thing I added for looks, but I moved the content around so that I didn't need it and I think that it looks better without it. I'm going to note that down though for future reference. Thanks!